# How to find and show a point value on the line?

Tags: plotting

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{eqns, f}, 


eqns = {y'[x] == 
     aa3*y[x]^3 + aa2*y[x]^2 + aa1*y[x] + aa0[t] + bb[t]/y[x], 
    y[0] == 15};

f = NDSolve[eqns, y, {x, 0, 1}][[1, 1, -1]]; 

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f[x]"}]], {{t, 20}, 0, 90,
   10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: **enter image description here**]

What code should I use to show the point on the line where $x = 0.85$?

Comment: Add this option to the `Plot` call: `Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Red, Point[{0.85, f[0.85]}]}`.